# R - transform output format of dplyr summarise

Tags: r, format, output, dplyr

I really appreciate using `summarise` from `dyplr`
to produce summary statistics.

However, I am not totally convinced about the "format" of the ouput.

For example :

```
mt = mtcars %>% 
 group_by(gear, vs) %>% 
 summarise(mean (disp) )
```

Will produce

```
  gear vs mean(disp)
1    3  0   357.6167
2    3  1   201.0333
3    4  0   160.0000
4    4  1   115.6200
5    5  0   229.3250
6    5  1    95.1000
```

For my scientific reports, I rather prefer display the output like this (whatever the statistical meaning of this `mtcars` example) :

```
  gear Mean Vs = 1 Mean Vs = 0
    3    201.0333    357.6167
    4    115.6200    160.0000
    5     95.1000    229.3250
```

Do you know if it is possible to "control" the output format of a `dplyr summarise` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `spread` from `tidyr` to extend your pipeline.  Note, I assigned a name for the mean so it could be referenced simply within the `spread` call.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(gear, vs) %>% 
    summarise(mean_disp = mean (disp) ) %>%
    spread(vs, mean_disp)

Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

  gear        0        1
1    3 357.6167 201.0333
2    4 160.0000 115.6200
3    5 229.3250  95.1000
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that `dcast` function of `reshape2` package can be useful for you.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mt, gear ~ vs)
Using mean(disp) as value column: use value.var to override.
  gear        0        1
1    3 357.6167 201.0333
2    4 160.0000 115.6200
3    5 229.3250  95.1000
```

Comment: You don't need to use OPs newly transformed data set, you can achieve the desired result using `mtcars` by just `dcast(mtcars, gear ~ vs, value.var = "disp", mean)`